# Change text of button based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have searched stackoverflow but i did not find any answers.

Please Check below html

```
<button type="button" class="nacnchor" value="1">hello</button>
<button type="button" class="nacnchor" value="2">hello</button>
<button type="button" class="nacnchor" value="3">hello</button>
```

I can change text of button based on class

```
$('button.nacnchor').text("REWRITE");
```

But i want to change the value based on attribute value , is ther anything like `$('button.nacnchor,attr(value=1)')` :p .

Comment: Are you asking how to select an element with a specific value? Or how to use the value attribute to change the text?

Comment: i need to change text of button based on its attribute "value" ...if i mention 1 it should change first button

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute selectors are documented here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
$("button.nacnchor[value='1']").text("REWRITE");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$("button[value='1']").text("REWRITE");
```

Comment: Well done, was just about to post myself showing how to do it INSTEAD of using the class

Answer (score 1):

When seeking how to use any given library it's always best to **R**ead **T**he **F**unny **M**anual [which has an entire page dedicated to this.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

> ...for example, `$("a[rel='nofollow']")`, will select `<a href="example.html" rel="nofollow">Some text</a>` but not `<a href="example.html" rel="nofollow foe">`Some text.
>
> Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.

- double quotes inside single quotes: `$('a[rel="nofollow self"]')`
- single quotes inside double quotes: `$("a[rel='nofollow self']")`
- escaped single quotes inside single quotes: `$('a[rel=\'nofollow self\']')`
- escaped double quotes inside double quotes: `$("a[rel=\"nofollow self\"]")`

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
$("button[value='1']").text("REWRITE");
```